# Sql server: how to get the value from a sql string

Tags: sql-server

This sql statement does not work.  After EXEC (@strSql), I see 0 or 1 as the result so I continue with IF statement but it doesn't work as I expected.  It doesn't take action from the IF statement.
Also, is there a way to make the query dynamic so I could check more than one table?

```
Declare @strSql varchar(1000),
@TableName varchar(100),
@linkedServer varchar(100)

Set @TableName='tablename'
Set @linkedServer='linkservername'
Set @strSql='Select count(1) as TabExists FROM DBC.TABLES WHERE
      TABLEKIND=''T'' AND DATABASENAME=''databasename'' AND 
      TABLENAME=''tablename'''
SET  @strSql = N'select TabExists from OPENQUERY('+@linkedServer+', ''' + REPLACE(@strSql, '''', '''''') + ''')'
EXEC (@strSql)

IF @strSql = '0'  --table not exist
    create table
IF @strSql = '1'  --table exist
delete data from table
```

Comment: I don't see how could you expect the `IF` to work differently, you are assigning a value to `@strSql` here: `SET  @strSql = N'select TabExists....`, and then you are doing `IF @strSql = '0' ...... IF @strSql = '1'` when `@strSql` it's clearly neither 0 nor 1

Comment: Why are you checking table existence in such a strange manner?

Comment: Is there a better way to check?  The tables I check are in teradata environment and I have to use linked server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead try

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @TabExists BIT;

Set @strSql = 'SELECT @TabExists = CASE WHEN TabExists = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
        FROM OPENQUERY(' + QUOTENAME(@linkedServer) 
        + ', ''SELECT TabExists = COUNT(*) 
                FROM LinkedDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = ' + @TableName + ');';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @strSQL, N'@TabExists BIT OUTPUT', @TabExists OUT;

IF (@TabExists = 0)
BEGIN
    -- create table
END;
```

Comment: The tables I check are in teradata environment and I have to use linked server.

Comment: The query does not work due to errors and it's hard to tell where errors are from.

Comment: I realized the problem is from QUOTENAME(@linkedServer) .  If I add SET @linkedServer='my link server name' after DECLARE, I get this error: Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'SELECT TabExists = COUNT(*) 
                FROM LinkedDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = my table name);'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'SELECT TabExists = COUNT(*) 
                FROM LinkedDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                WHERE TABLE_NAME = my table name'.

Comment: I have managed to work it out based on the query Elena provided: